# I have multiple installs of wordpress, all using the same plugins but in different locations. how can i use a symlink link to avoid duplication?

Tags: unix, centos, symbolic-link

I have multiple installations of wordpress on my server, all using the same plugins but in different locations.

i.e i have

```
/home/site1/wp-content/plugins/plugin1
/home/site1/wp-content/plugins/plugin2
```

How can I use a symbolic link link to avoid duplication?

(I can't install them all on same location due to some requirements I have)

Comment: What are your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand. Your question shows two plugins at the same location. I will assume you want to link to a different location.

Assuming links will work, do this:

```
$ ln -s /home/site1/wp-content/plugins/plugin1 /home/site2/wp-content/plugins/plugin1
```